# How to properly execute collision detection between two spheres?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

Hello world :) Working on a small animation in which a bunch of spheres jump around the canvas, bouncing off of eachother, floors, walls, and ceilings.

Now, this works perfectly with no failures, until I add more spheres than can fit in the area in one level. At this point, the spheres sink to one flat level of spheres, coinjoining into eachother and pushing others through wall boundaries, which doesn't normally happen.

However, it should be stated I don't fully understand the function I am using to achieve the outcome, so that likely has something to do with it. Will post my collision detection functions below, and hopefully one of you can help me get a bit farther :)

#### Borrowed Functions:

```
/**
 * Rotates coordinate system for velocities
 *
 * Takes velocities and alters them as if the coordinate system they're on was rotated
 *
 * @param  Object | velocity | The velocity of an individual particle
 * @param  Float  | angle    | The angle of collision between two objects in radians
 * @return Object | The altered x and y velocities after the coordinate system has been rotated
 */

function rotate(velocity, angle) {
    const rotatedVelocities = {
        x: velocity.x * Math.cos(angle) - velocity.y * Math.sin(angle),
        y: velocity.x * Math.sin(angle) + velocity.y * Math.cos(angle)
    };

    return rotatedVelocities;
}

/**
 * Swaps out two colliding particles' x and y velocities after running through
 * an elastic collision reaction equation
 *
 * @param  Object | particle      | A particle object with x and y coordinates, plus velocity
 * @param  Object | otherParticle | A particle object with x and y coordinates, plus velocity
 * @return Null | Does not return a value
 */

function resolveCollision(particle, otherParticle) {
    const xVelocityDiff = particle.velocity.x - otherParticle.velocity.x;
    const yVelocityDiff = particle.velocity.y - otherParticle.velocity.y;
    console.log("Resolving");

    const xDist = otherParticle.x - particle.x;
    const yDist = otherParticle.y - particle.y;
    // alert(xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist)

    // Prevent accidental overlap of particles
    if (xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0) {
        console.log("Resolving IF");

        // Grab angle between the two colliding particles
        const angle = -Math.atan2(otherParticle.y - particle.y, otherParticle.x - particle.x);

        // Store mass in var for better readability in collision equation
        const m1 = particle.mass;
        const m2 = otherParticle.mass;

        // Velocity before equation
        const u1 = rotate(particle.velocity, angle);
        const u2 = rotate(otherParticle.velocity, angle);

        // Velocity after 1d collision equation
        const v1 = { x: u1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: u1.y };
        const v2 = { x: u2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: u2.y };

        // Final velocity after rotating axis back to original location
        const vFinal1 = rotate(v1, -angle);
        const vFinal2 = rotate(v2, -angle);

        // Swap particle velocities for realistic bounce effect
        particle.velocity.x = vFinal1.x;
        particle.velocity.y = vFinal1.y;

        otherParticle.velocity.x = vFinal2.x;
        otherParticle.velocity.y = vFinal2.y;
    }
}
```

### Ball Properties:

```
// Objects
function Ball(x, y, dy, dx, radius, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    // this.dy = dy;
    // this.dx = dx;
    this.velocity = {
        x:dx,
        y:dy
    }
    this.radius = radius
    this.color = color
    this.mass = 1;

    this.collision = ()=> {
        for (var index = 0; index < objects.length; index++) {
            var coin = objects[index];
            if (this === coin) {
                continue;
            }
            if (getDistance(this.x, this.y, coin.x, coin.y) - (this.radius + coin.radius) < 0) {
                // alert('hi');
                console.log("collision:");

                resolveCollision(this, coin)
            }
        }
    }
}




Ball.prototype.update = function() {
    if (this.y + this.radius + this.velocity.y > canvas.height) {
        this.velocity.y = (-this.velocity.y * parseFloat(0.85));

    }else {
        this.velocity.y += gravity;
    }
    this.y += this.velocity.y;
    this.x += this.velocity.x;

    if (this.x + this.radius + this.velocity.x > canvas.width) {
        this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x;

    }
    if (Math.sign(this.velocity.x) === 1) {
        this.velocity.x -= 0.01;
    } else if (Math.sign(this.velocity.x) === -1) {
        this.velocity.x += 0.01;


    }
    if (this.x - this.radius - this.velocity.x < 0) {
        this.velocity.x = Math.abs(this.velocity.x);
       }






    this.draw()
}
```

Any help here really would be most appreciated, I am trying to improve my skills in this field, and feel a strong need to go back and read my geometry books again :D

Comment: The most robust way to prevent this phenomenon is to always resolve the  immediate next collision first, because it is the only one which will be unaffected by other collisions that may occur during the timestep. This requires calculating the precise time delta at which each pair of circles will collide - the solution of a quadratic equation. Needless to say this gets very laborious for a large number of circles in close proximity of each other, so you may need to look at broadphase techniques like quad-trees.